# Azure Application error, but no issue in the logs

Tags: azure-web-app-service

It is really frustrating as I am not able to resolve this issue of Application error. The app is up and running however when I try to access via azure URL, it gives the application error. Help would be appreciated

[The error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JAnuH.png)

[No issue in the logs, app is up and running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hotVn.png)

Comment: do you see anything out of place in the `network` tab in the development tools? this error may be due to a configuration issue.

Comment: Please provide more information, like what language do you use? What's your deployment methods? Use Linux or Windows?

Comment: Has your problem been solved? Is there any progress?

Answer (score 0):

Your webapp is deployed on the Linux platform, and it is temporarily unclear what language your webapp is written in from the log.

**Regarding the problem of Application Error, we usually add Startup Command to solve this problem.**

*Prerequisites:*

1. Make sure that the port defined in the code uses the process.env.PORT parameter.
2. Example: In the nodejs project, when we are testing locally, we can define it like this:

   ```
   const port = 8081 || process.env.PORT.
   ```

   Then we need to add the startup command.

   ① If it is a vue project, the recommended command is

   ```
   pm2 serve /home/site/wwwroot --no-daemon --spa
   ```

   ②If it is react or angular, it is recommended to use

   ```
   npx serve -s
   ```
3. If you are using Python, you can refer to the following document.

   [Configure a custom startup file for Python apps on Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/python/tutorial-deploy-app-service-on-linux-04)

Comment: App is in Python (poorly, dash) and we are trying docker image via azure container registry. It was perfectly fine and we managed to deploy another app couple of month ago. However, we are struggling to find out the way this time although all the procedure is same for deployment!

Comment: @Qazi Flask or django ?

Comment: Its a dashboard using plotly dash

Comment: Did you manage to solve the issue. I am also trying to deploy dash in azure but it always default page and says code missing although reference is available